# Spring @Autowired - No qualifying bean of type 'com.pc.visitor.visitorrepository'

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code, autowired

I am using the @Autowire annotation (Spring Maven Project). The following webservice/api works fine. Until I add the @Autowire annotation in post.java.

**Project Path / Files**:

- pcbackend > visitor > pom.xml
- pcbackend > visitor > src > main > visitor > Application.java
- pcbackend > visitor > src > main > visitor > newvisitor.java
- pcbackend > visitor > src > main > visitor > visitorrepository.java
- pcbackend > visitor > src > main > visitor > post.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pc</groupId>
    <artifactId>visitor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
package com.pc.visitor;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication()
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);


    }

}
```

```
package com.pc.visitor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name = "visitors")
public class newvisitor {

    @NotBlank
    private String firstname;
    @NotBlank
    private String lastname;
    @NotBlank
    private String month;
    @NotBlank
    private String day;
    @NotBlank
    private String year;
    @NotBlank
    private String socialsecuritynumber;
    @NotBlank
    private String street1;
    private String street2;
    @NotBlank
    private String city;
    @NotBlank
    private String state;
    @NotBlank
    private String zip;
    @NotBlank
    private String phone;
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    public newvisitor(){
        super();
    }

    public newvisitor(String firstname, String lastname, String month, String day, String year, String socialsecuritynumber, String street1, String street2, String city, String state, String zip, String phone, String email) {
        super();

        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.day = year;
        this.day = socialsecuritynumber;
        this.day = street1;
        this.day = street2;
        this.day = city;
        this.day = state;
        this.day = zip;
        this.day = phone;
        this.day = email;
    }




    /**
     * @return String return the firstname
     */
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstname the firstname to set
     */
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the lastname
     */
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastname the lastname to set
     */
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the month
     */
    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    /**
     * @param month the month to set
     */
    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the day
     */
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    /**
     * @param day the day to set
     */
    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the year
     */
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    /**
     * @param year the year to set
     */
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the socialsecuritynumber
     */
    public String getSocialsecuritynumber() {
        return socialsecuritynumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param socialsecuritynumber the socialsecuritynumber to set
     */
    public void setSocialsecuritynumber(String socialsecuritynumber) {
        this.socialsecuritynumber = socialsecuritynumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the street1
     */
    public String getStreet1() {
        return street1;
    }

    /**
     * @param street1 the street1 to set
     */
    public void setStreet1(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the street2
     */
    public String getStreet2() {
        return street2;
    }

    /**
     * @param street2 the street2 to set
     */
    public void setStreet2(String street2) {
        this.street2 = street2;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the state
     */
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * @param state the state to set
     */
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the zip
     */
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    /**
     * @param zip the zip to set
     */
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the phone
     */
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    /**
     * @param phone the phone to set
     */
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

```
package com.pc.visitor;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface visitorrepository extends JpaRepository<newvisitor, Long> {
}
```

```
package com.pc.visitor;


import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class post {

    //@Autowired
    visitorrepository visitorrepository;

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public void insert(@Valid @RequestBody newvisitor newvisitor) {

    }

}
```

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field visitorrepository in com.pc.visitor.post required a bean of type 'com.pc.visitor.visitorrepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pc.visitor.visitorrepository' in your configuration.
```

I have a feeling that I am suppose to be using some of these other annotations like @service, @component,  @controller, @configuration, or even @componentscan etc. I just can't figure out where to list these things.

Any ideas as to what I need to do? Like I said, everything works perfect with the @Autowired commented out.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you try following options: if JpaRepository is not needed specifically, change it with CrudRepository. Or if you need JpaRepository, then add @EnableJpaRepositories("com.pc.visitor") on your main application along with @SpringBootApplication annotation

Comment: when you add `@Autowired` in the RestController class you are getting the *required a bean of type* is it?

Comment: This should work fine, you may share the github link if possible

Comment: For starters your dependencies are a mess. Remove the `org.springframework.data` dependencies and use the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` instead. You don't need the `jackson-databind` either as that is also included in the `spring-boot-starter-web` by default. And do you really need eclipselink or use the default Hibernate (which works automatically) for eclpse link you need to do some setup yourself.

Comment: If you need to use eclipselink instead of hibernate, see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-eclipselink

Comment: @sTekin what is the difference between CrudRepository and JpaRepository? What are the PROs and CONs of each?

Comment: @M. Deinum, Ha! When I posted this I knew I was going to get slack for the dependencies, I haven't spent much time digging into the spring helper dependencies, so have kinda fumbled my way through. Although, I did take your advice and adjusted and things look better in that file now, ultimately this did not solve the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @出羽和之 I don't think I needed the eclipse dependency either, so I removed that as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NewDeveloper JpaRepository extends from CrudRepository (there is another one between them; PagingAndSortingRepository), so JpaRepository has some additional methods. You can check their definition and see their methods. But the thing is that JpaRepository are not auto-enabled by default, you need to add explicitly, that is why i asked you to add @EnableJpaRepositories("com.pc.visitor") or change it to CrudRepository

Comment: Ultimately the solution here was that I did not have an @Id annotation with a long type variable specified in the "newvisitor.java" file.

Comment: @sTekin, that makes sense for the most part. I will have to look into what makes most sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An @Id annotation was required in my newvisitor.java file/class.

```
package com.pc.visitor;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "visitors")
public class newvisitor {

    @Id
    private long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String firstname;
    @NotBlank
    private String lastname;
    @NotBlank
    private String month;
    @NotBlank
    private String day;
    @NotBlank
    private String year;
    @NotBlank
    private String socialsecuritynumber;
    @NotBlank
    private String street1;
    private String street2;
    @NotBlank
    private String city;
    @NotBlank
    private String state;
    @NotBlank
    private String zip;
    @NotBlank
    private String phone;
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    public newvisitor(){
        super();
    }

    public newvisitor(String firstname, String lastname, String month, String day, String year, String socialsecuritynumber, String street1, String street2, String city, String state, String zip, String phone, String email) {
        super();

        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.day = year;
        this.day = socialsecuritynumber;
        this.day = street1;
        this.day = street2;
        this.day = city;
        this.day = state;
        this.day = zip;
        this.day = phone;
        this.day = email;
    }




    /**
     * @return String return the firstname
     */
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstname the firstname to set
     */
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the lastname
     */
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastname the lastname to set
     */
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the month
     */
    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    /**
     * @param month the month to set
     */
    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the day
     */
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    /**
     * @param day the day to set
     */
    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the year
     */
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    /**
     * @param year the year to set
     */
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the socialsecuritynumber
     */
    public String getSocialsecuritynumber() {
        return socialsecuritynumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param socialsecuritynumber the socialsecuritynumber to set
     */
    public void setSocialsecuritynumber(String socialsecuritynumber) {
        this.socialsecuritynumber = socialsecuritynumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the street1
     */
    public String getStreet1() {
        return street1;
    }

    /**
     * @param street1 the street1 to set
     */
    public void setStreet1(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the street2
     */
    public String getStreet2() {
        return street2;
    }

    /**
     * @param street2 the street2 to set
     */
    public void setStreet2(String street2) {
        this.street2 = street2;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the state
     */
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * @param state the state to set
     */
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the zip
     */
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    /**
     * @param zip the zip to set
     */
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the phone
     */
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    /**
     * @param phone the phone to set
     */
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

You may use [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/), which generates Spring Boot project structure.

You need to add these dependencies at least:

- Spring Web
- Spring Data JPA
- Validation (If using [2.3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters) or later)
- MySQL Driver

Using this generated codes, `pom.xml` will be fixed.

(Note: Spring Boot uses [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) as JPA implementation by default, not [EclipseLink](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/).)

---

2.

[JPA Entity needs an identifier(primary key)](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-intro002.html#_primary_keys_in_entities).

you have decided that identifier type of `newvisitor` is `Long`

```java
public interface visitorrepository extends JpaRepository<newvisitor, Long> {
}
```

, so `newvisitor` needs `Long` type field decorated by `@Id` annotation.
For example:

```java
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class newvisitor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is how I have it now, what does "GeneratedValue" do though?

Comment: Setting for id auto-generation. [Here](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) is a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that might help:

1. The package structure presented in the question if not compliant with maven conventions:

You should use:

`src/main/java/com/pc/visitor`

And place all the files there

2. Name classes in accordance with Java Naming conventions. Case matters:

newvisitor --> NewVisitor
post --> Post
visitorrepository  --> VisitorRepository

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your package inside src/main/java
2. Follow java naming convention to create class name.
3. Spring data JPA by default uses Hibernate though that could not be the reason to through @Autowire  error.
4. Entity class should have a field marked as @Id.

Comment: I misspoke on path files, it follows the standard, src > main > java > com > pc > visitor > file. All other points make sense, thanks for taking the time to respond. I was able to solve by adding the @Id.